# At/With/On Short Notice

Tags: word-choice, prepositions, at-with

I have heard people use on/at short notice

> sorry to call a meeting **on/at** such short notice

but is it grammatically correct to use "with short notice".

Example:

> I wish you had not called a meeting **with** such short notice.

Answer (score 2):

All three are common and idiomatic.

Based on my resourses, *"**at** short notice"* tends to be British English - so perhaps *"**on** short notice"* is more American.

*"**With** short notice"* is, as I said, correct and to me personally there is nothing wrong with using all of them interchangeably.
But you should ask your teacher or mentor which style of the interpretation they prefer.

Dictionaries may not consider *"**with** short notice"* a well-established phrase but that doesn't necessarily mean it's wrong.

- Expressions with the same meaning: on/at/with a moment's notice.

Comment: Thanks for your response! Is it correct to say "sorry for the late notice?"

Comment: Yes. Absolutely.

Answer (score -4):

No, it's not grammatically correct to say 'with such short notice'. The correct way to say it is 'at such short notice'.

Comment: Thanks for your input! Is it correct to say "sorry for the short notice?"